# Compare MongoDB Collections

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a program that is pulling all user data from my system and storing all the information in a single MongoDB collection. I am doing this each day and want to compare today's collection to yesterday's and see if any users were added/deleted/modified.

I have seen there is a Mongo command to compare, but that returns true/false. I am looking for a report of all changes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? Due to the `_id` field, the two collections will be different in any case.

Comment: If users insert data today in one collection and the next day in another collection then they are distinct in any case. Again, what exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: I guess any field other than _id. A few examples of what I am looking to see: are there records one day not in the other (added/removed users) and if specific fields changed (active==true; active==false)